# If statement issue, still activating when arguments are not valid

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure what's happening, when the if statement `if (score.value >= cCost.value) {...}` is called and the score is >= 2 (cCost is 100) the if statement will still activate and make my score go negative even with the input min is 0.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" id="score" readonly>
<input type="number" value="100" min="100" id="cCost" readonly>
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" id="clickers" readonly>
```

JS Code:

```
function updateNums() {
    document.querySelector('#score').value = score.value;
    document.querySelector('#clickers').value = clickers.value;
    document.querySelector('#cCost').value = cCost.value;
}

function addClicker() {
    var score = document.querySelector('#score');
    var cCost = document.querySelector('#cCost');
    var clickers = document.querySelector('#clickers');

    if (score.value >= cCost.value) {
        score.value = parseInt(score.value) - parseInt(cCost.value);
        cCost.value = Math.round(parseInt(cCost.value) * 1.50);
        clickers.value = parseInt(clickers.value) + 1;

        updateNums();
    } else {
        alert("You Do Not Have Enough Score To Buy This.");
    }
}
```

```js
function updateNums() {
    document.querySelector('#score').value = score.value;
    document.querySelector('#clickers').value = clickers.value;
    document.querySelector('#cCost').value = cCost.value;
}


function addClicker() {
    var score = document.querySelector('#score');
    var cCost = document.querySelector('#cCost');
    var clickers = document.querySelector('#clickers');
    
    debugger;
    console.log(score.value, cCost.value)

    if (score.value >= cCost.value) {
        score.value = parseInt(score.value) - parseInt(cCost.value);
        cCost.value = Math.round(parseInt(cCost.value) * 1.50);
        clickers.value = parseInt(clickers.value) + 1;

        updateNums();
    } else {
        alert("You Do Not Have Enough Score To Buy This.");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1000" min="1000" id="score" readonly>
<input type="number" value="100" min="100" id="cCost" readonly>
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" id="clickers" readonly>

<button onclick="addClicker()">Click</button>
```

Comment: You're comparing strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Adding `score = parseInt(score); cCost = parseInt(cCost);` before the if statement fixed it.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822981/comparing-two-numbers-from-a-form-in-javascript)

Comment: just use this => `if (parseInt(score.value) - parseInt(cCost.value))`